# Предел (или предела) не существует?

Tags: падежи

Один из распространённых типов задач в высшей математике: проверить, существует ли предел последовательности.
Как лучше отрицательно ответить на этот вопрос:

"предел не существует" или "предела не существует"?

В добротных советских изданиях можно встретить оба варианта. В том числе без контекста — просто как ответ на задачу в конце учебника. В современных изданиях чаще используют родительный падеж.

Вероятно, допустимы оба варианта. Но интересно было бы услышать любое мнение (или ссылки на источники) о предпочтениях / причинах / тенденциях. Я видел интересные научные статьи о борьбе родительного с винительным, но чтобы с именительным — такое даже не приходило в голову.

Comment: См. ответ на подобный вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435119/%d0%98%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустимы оба варианта. Если сомневаетесь, замените: "последовательность не имеет предела".

Это лучше звучит, чем "предел не существует" или "предела не существует". А возможны все варианты, зависит от Ваших предпочтений. Научный язык допускает все конструкции, лишь бы мысль была выражена точно.

Comment: Людмила>> _Научный язык допускает все конструкции, лишь бы мысль была выражена точно._ 
Конечно, но только грамматически допустимые конструкции :) И как раз это мне было важно уточнить. Спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

Стиль математического изложения отдает предпочтение именительному падежу. Предел не существует.