# Именительный или родительный падеж?

Tags: падежи

Регулируется ли какими-то правилами использование именительного или родительного падежа в приведенных ниже (и подобных) выражениях?

```
этот мир не существует        (этого мира не существует)
указанный адрес не существует (указанного адреса не существует)
такое слово не существует     (такого слова не существует)
```

В заслуживающих доверия источниках в таких выражениях встречается и тот, и другой падеж. Я думаю, что именительный падеж в подобных конструкциях может использоваться только в редких случаях. Но я не смог найти никакого правила.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нельзя регулировать правилами использование разных конструкций, потому и богат русский язык, что одно и то же мы можем сказать с помощью разных предложений.

Этот мир не существует   -двусоставное предложение. Этого мира не существует. - безличное. Этого мира нет. - безличное.

Указанный адрес не существует.-двусоставное. Указанного адреса не существует(нет).-безличное.

Такое слово не существует. - двусоставное. Такого слова не существует.-безличное.

Более того, безличные предложения чаще всего  возникали на основе эллипсиса подлежащего, которое из-за обобщенности или неопределенности значения становится излишним. Ср.: На дворе все спокойно. - На дворе спокойно. Предложения с формальными подлежащими это и все (Чудесно! - Это чудесно!; Им все тяжело. - Им тяжело) сочетают в себе свойства личных и безличных предложений.

Вторые структуры в Ваших примерах - безлично-генитивные предложения, структурной особенностью которых является наличие отрицательного слова в сочетании с родительным падежом. Например, отрицательное слово нет: Нет уже ни положения в обществе, ни прежней чести, ни права приглашать к себе в гости (Ч.); ...Там счету нет столетьям (Щип.); Нет меры нашему Познанью (Бл.);

безличная форма глаголов быть, стать, показаться с отрицанием: Не было ни гроша, да вдруг алтын (посл.); Раздался сиплый глухой лай, но даже собаки не показалось (Т.); Любви без рубцов и жертв не бывает (Паст.);

существительное в форме родительного падежа с отрицанием ни: Ни звука!.. И видишь ты синий свод неба... (Н.); Ни писем, ни вестей. Как ни проси их, они забыли (Сим.);

отрицательные местоимения ничего, никого и др.: - Кажется, кто-то там... - Никого (Ч.).

Предложения, в предикативную основу которых входит отрицательное слово, академическая Грамматика-80 относит к двухкомпонентным типа Нет времени; Ни звука; Ничего нового; Ни единой ошибки; Некому работать (см.: Русская грамматика. Т. 2. С. 336).

Таким образом, **именительный падеж употребляется в подлежащем двусоставного предложения, а родительный в безлично-генитивных**. При этом в школьной грамматике генитив (родительный падеж сущ.) является дополнением, в академической разные точки зрения, кто-то относит генитив к грамматической основе и считает его тоже сказуемым, а кто-то к дополнениям.

Comment: _Людмила: кто-то относит генитив к грамматической основе и считает его тоже **сказуемым**..._ === Сказуемым ли?

Comment: Людмила, спасибо за развёрнутый ответ. Он помог мне исправить понимание.

Comment: Я говорю только о безлично-генитивных - слёз у меня не было. Кто-то разбирает как сказуемое "Не было", а кто-то "Не было слёз". А чисто генитивные разбираются как отдельные независимые предложения и не относятся к односоставным вообще, там просто говорится "главный член предложения" без отнесения к подлежащему или сказуемому. Правда, кто-то до сих пор относит его к предложениям с главным членом подлежащим - субстантивным бытийным.

Answer (score 0):

Стилистическая разница существует. Она имеет два аспекта.

1) *Этот мир не существует.* || Делается акцент на подлежащем. Характерно для юриспруденции (*указанный адрес не существует*).
*Этого мира не существует.* || Делается акцент на сказуемом.

2) Проявляется при слове "*такой*":
*Такое не может случиться.* || Именно такое (о чём было сказано ранее). Конкретика.
*Такого не может случиться.* || Подобного (в широком смысле) или о чём-то в общем.
(То есть во втором аспекте проявляются стандартные особенности этих падежей.)