# "Такого не может случиться" или "Такое не может случиться"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как лучше: "Такого не может случиться " или "Такое не может случиться"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оба варианта имеют право на существование. Первый вариант встречается чаще. Пример из Нацкорпуса:

> Такого не может случиться. Это не аллеи, а просто коридор, обсаженный кустами. (Виктор Пелевин)

Стилистика использования этих выражений немного отличается, но не настолько, чтобы я смог сформулировать это отличие достаточно чётко. Возможно, ответ на [этот вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435119/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6/) здесь также будет полезен.

Answer (score 0):

Правильнее второе. Сравните: такое случается раз в сто лет. У вас подразумевается некое событие, которое не может произойти. А если вы хотите употребить местоимение "такого", лучше сказать так: такого не может быть.

Answer (score 0):

Если под "таким" подразумевается что-то конкретное, то:
*Такое не может случиться.*

А если подразумевается подобное (в широком смысле) или говорится о чём-то общем, то:
*Такого не может случиться.*

Например:

*- Может ли обычная курица взлететь на километр?

- Нет, [именно] такое не может случиться.*

*- Могут ли животные говорить, как в сказках?

- Нет, такого [в общем] не может случится.*