# Как правильно "Указанный путь не существует" или "Указанного пути не существует"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, словоизменение

Как правильно:

> Файл не был создан, так как указанный путь не существует.

или

> Файл не был создан, так как указанного пути не существует.

?

Нашёл [похожий вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435098/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82), но не уверен, что правило то же.

Comment: Для предложений про работу системы характерна точность. Это в пользу именительного. Плюс "указанный" задаёт конкретику. А с родительным плавнее звучит, не так резко.